# How to assign a SSL Certificate to S3 bucket using C# SDK to Enable HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I have created a S3 bucket and uploaded the two files to the bucket via AWS .Net SDK, I can access files with HTTP, but I need access the files with HTTPS (SSL Secured) for that I have created the certificate request using the `RequestCertificateAsync` method of `AmazonCertificateManagerClient`, but I couldn't find a way to assign the created certificate to the specific bucket via programmatically.

This is the code I have used to request the certificate

```
public static void CertificateCreation()
{
     AmazonCertificateManagerConfig acmConfig = new AmazonCertificateManagerConfig();
     var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(accessKeyID, secretKey);
     acmConfig.RegionEndpoint = Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USWest1;
     AmazonCertificateManagerClient client = new AmazonCertificateManagerClient(credentials, acmConfig);

     RequestCertificateRequest request = new RequestCertificateRequest()
     {
         CertificateAuthorityArn = "arn-value",
         DomainName = "damain_name",
         ValidationMethod = "DNS",
     };

     var response = client.RequestCertificateAsync(request);

     while (TaskStatus.Created == client.RequestCertificateAsync(request).Status)
     {
          Console.WriteLine("Change is pending.");
            Thread.Sleep(15000);
     }
}
```

I doesn't have idea to move further, to assign the SSL certificate to specific bucket. Is anyone can help to accomplish this task much appreciated.

Comment: How did it go with the issue? The issue persists?

Comment: Yes, still I have the issue, Have to enable the HTTPS to S3 bucket

Comment: Did you try to follow any of the links I provided to setup CloudFromt?

Comment: I need to do this using programmatically for the automation @Ma

Answer (score 2):

You **can't** setup SSL cert directly on your bucket website. The way to do it is through [CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) (CF). So you would front your bucket website with CF distribution.

By **default** CF gives your HTTPS and its own random domain. If you prefare to have custom domain, you have to buy one and get SSL certificate for it from ACM. Then you associated the domain and the cert with your CF distro:

- [How do I use CloudFront to serve HTTPS requests for my Amazon S3 bucket?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-https-requests-s3/)
- [How do I use CloudFront to serve a static website hosted on Amazon S3?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-serve-static-website/)
- [Amazon S3 + Amazon CloudFront: A Match Made in the Cloud](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/amazon-s3-amazon-cloudfront-a-match-made-in-the-cloud/)